# How to disable VS Code hover click menu items

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Studio Code and wondering How to disable the hover click (Auto Click) Menu items behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that issue once. Each time I was just hovering my mouse over any menu item for a split second, it was getting clicked!

I found out that it was because of a hovering translation application that I was using (called VerbAce).

Try to terminate all applications except for Vscode to see which application is causing that issue.

Comment: thanks a lot ... that's it. I'm using VerbAce too and it was the cause of the problem, it was very irritating.